# Heroku push issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am having an issue with pushing my app to Heroku. Below is my terminal output when I try to use "git push heroku master"

```
Counting objects: 22, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (22/22), done.
Writing objects: 100% (22/22), 2.16 KiB | 2.16 MiB/s, done.
Total 22 (delta 15), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.5.1
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.15.2
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.16.4). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
remote:        Using rake 12.3.1
remote:        Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
remote:        Using minitest 5.11.3
remote:        Using thread_safe 0.3.6
remote:        Using builder 3.2.3
remote:        Using erubi 1.7.1
remote:        Using mini_portile2 2.3.0
remote:        Using crass 1.0.4
remote:        Using rack 2.0.5
remote:        Using nio4r 2.3.1
remote:        Using websocket-extensions 0.1.3
remote:        Using mini_mime 1.0.0
remote:        Using arel 9.0.0
remote:        Using mimemagic 0.3.2
remote:        Using bcrypt 3.1.12
remote:        Using msgpack 1.2.4
remote:        Using bundler 1.15.2
remote:        Using cancancan 2.2.0
remote:        Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
remote:        Using execjs 2.7.0
remote:        Using method_source 0.9.0
remote:        Using thor 0.20.0
remote:        Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
remote:        Using ffi 1.9.25
remote:        Using multi_json 1.13.1
remote:        Using pg 1.0.0
remote:        Using puma 3.12.0
remote:        Using rb-fsevent 0.10.3
remote:        Using tilt 2.0.8
remote:        Using turbolinks-source 5.1.0
remote:        Fetching will_paginate 3.1.6
remote:        Using tzinfo 1.2.5
remote:        Using nokogiri 1.8.4
remote:        Using i18n 1.1.0
remote:        Using rack-test 1.1.0
remote:        Using warden 1.2.7
remote:        Using sprockets 3.7.2
remote:        Using mail 2.7.0
remote:        Using websocket-driver 0.7.0
remote:        Using marcel 0.3.2
remote:        Using coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Using uglifier 4.1.18
remote:        Using rb-inotify 0.9.10
remote:        Using bootsnap 1.3.1
remote:        Using turbolinks 5.1.1
remote:        Using loofah 2.2.2
remote:        Using activesupport 5.2.1
remote:        Using sass-listen 4.0.0
remote:        Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.4
remote:        Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
remote:        Using globalid 0.4.1
remote:        Using activemodel 5.2.1
remote:        Using jbuilder 2.7.0
remote:        Using sass 3.5.7
remote:        Using actionview 5.2.1
remote:        Using activejob 5.2.1
remote:        Using activerecord 5.2.1
remote:        Using actionpack 5.2.1
remote:        Using actioncable 5.2.1
remote:        Using actionmailer 5.2.1
remote:        Using activestorage 5.2.1
remote:        Using railties 5.2.1
remote:        Using sprockets-rails 3.2.1
remote:        Using coffee-rails 4.2.2
remote:        Using responders 2.4.0
remote:        Using jquery-rails 4.3.3
remote:        Using rails 5.2.1
remote:        Using sass-rails 5.0.7
remote:        Using devise 4.5.0
remote:        Installing will_paginate 3.1.6
remote:        Bundle complete! 20 Gemfile dependencies, 69 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
remote:        Bundle completed (3.33s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote:        Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.16.4). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        The latest bundler is 1.16.4, but you are currently running 1.15.2.
remote:        To update, run `gem install bundler`
remote: -----> Installing node-v8.10.0-linux-x64
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        Yarn executable was not detected in the system.
remote:        Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
remote:        I, [2018-09-10T13:46:40.231019 #394]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/public/assets/0-2f224f1c26eb187a4e48a623951f607419e6582b45063cb2a247ed92b2dee9fd.png
remote:        I, [2018-09-10T13:46:40.233643 #394]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/public/assets/1-e939388a981a2f5d794dc2c45f36224116d5d457d766baccfbafaab654933b89.png
remote:        I, [2018-09-10T13:46:40.236052 #394]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/public/assets/2-c97fc71270db08081907559965118e78d296b15ead96645a309f0098bbfc9ab4.png
remote:        I, [2018-09-10T13:46:40.238092 #394]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/public/assets/3-0fd2895b84fe6c3fe38b92e1282c65fab8b7b74fc6e92f8827d65451910d6ba4.png
remote:        I, [2018-09-10T13:46:40.240552 #394]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/public/assets/4-de0b5807f5a4eeb9e90e6d171904ec57848010b65d20494419565f8424884c60.png
remote:        I, [2018-09-10T13:46:40.242957 #394]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/public/assets/5-8dd2b09aa49f1caf833c87cc4bcb7700d31dc842e82c2fa60ddf84635af5693d.png
remote:        I, [2018-09-10T13:46:40.249959 #394]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/public/assets/cancel-custom-off-e7d2ac9d0d0574c9b41e3f4b838a258d31f491f3ce616b695295b5754897528d.png
remote:        I, [2018-09-10T13:46:40.252393 #394]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/public/assets/cancel-custom-on-e801e71a9008b085e080ca40ded7c86ee0aebcc5baee50f5c8282a1d4d14404d.png
remote:        I, [2018-09-10T13:46:40.254896 #394]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/public/assets/cancel-off-5758f74356b87443c8dd8d07a98b4be8b9e5b0a6304baf27bbd2b99d8e02d01c.png
remote:        I, [2018-09-10T13:46:40.256937 #394]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/public/assets/cancel-on-52afce0580c4df0b09e2302d54750e9d7b882b7c6c6847a16c98f606b2451389.png
remote:        I, [2018-09-10T13:46:40.363704 #394]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/public/assets/off-12ebbed5d82fd3c5e97d907750d59738e230e120a2c6310a75f698f4e9a02d43.png
remote:        I, [2018-09-10T13:46:40.366453 #394]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/public/assets/on-a138853be3ec7e6cb69a9e761fe1a2fe5985d17c2463a277f8da4a5ca7598039.png
remote:        I, [2018-09-10T13:46:40.379200 #394]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/public/assets/star-half-mono-2faa84c4e49ad062e611850004ec93ec89760d221400969a70918b4248b333df.png
remote:        I, [2018-09-10T13:46:40.381479 #394]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/public/assets/star-half-808ffaeee4006e4930f89f5dcf46f603eb173ecc365b8f3df2b822bb6747c0b8.png
remote:        I, [2018-09-10T13:46:40.383760 #394]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/public/assets/star-off-cf9b07584547d5d561dfac9cdbf7b6a530cb72a1b7a1096411966036c4017d38.png
remote:        I, [2018-09-10T13:46:40.385981 #394]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/public/assets/star-on-88233ad1abcd2282b53edb9465a6bef42fd32de319f014e4059353e4fd8a7e0a.png
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        Uglifier::Error: Unexpected token name «scoreName», expected punc «,». To use ES6 syntax, harmony mode must be enabled with Uglifier.new(:harmony => true).
remote:        /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/uglifier-4.1.18/lib/uglifier.rb:234:in `parse_result'
remote:        /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/uglifier-4.1.18/lib/uglifier.rb:216:in `run_uglifyjs'
remote:        /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/uglifier-4.1.18/lib/uglifier.rb:168:in `compile'
remote:        /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:53:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:28:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor
remote:        /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
remote:        /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
remote:        /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
remote:        /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
remote:        /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
remote:        /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
remote:        /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in `block in find'
remote:        /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:228:in `block in stat_tree
remote:        /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:212:in `block in stat_directory'
remote:        /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `stat_directory'
remote:        /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:227:in `stat_tree'
remote:        /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths
remote:        /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in `find'
remote:        /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:186:in `compile'
remote:        /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in `block (3 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
remote:        /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_d03dd820f3a6d398522db8ceeafe1812/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to whispering-springs-21097.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/whispering-springs-21097.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

Below is also my gemfile.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
group :development, :test do
gem 'sqlite3'
end
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.3', '>= 4.3.3'
# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end


# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
gem 'devise', '~> 4.5'
gem 'cancancan', '~> 2.2'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1.0'
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

I am able to push the code to github without any problems. However, Heroku seems to keep coming up with the same issue.

Below is also my production.rb file.

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "whispering-springs-21097
.herokuapp.com" }
  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Ensures that a master key has been made available in either ENV["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"]
  # or in config/master.key. This key is used to decrypt credentials (and other encrypted files).
  # config.require_master_key = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = true

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Store uploaded files on the local file system (see config/storage.yml for options)
  config.active_storage.service = :local

  # Mount Action Cable outside main process or domain
  # config.action_cable.mount_path = nil
  # config.action_cable.url = 'wss://example.com/cable'
  # config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'http://example.com', /http:\/\/example.*/ ]

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate queues per environment)
  # config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque
  # config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "nameofapp_#{Rails.env}"

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # require 'syslog/logger'
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new 'app-name')

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us the JavaScript code around `scoreName`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Uglifier::Error: Unexpected token name «scoreName», expected punc «,».
>   To use ES6 syntax, harmony mode must be enabled with
>   Uglifier.new(:harmony => true)

You just need to change

```
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
```

to

```
config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(harmony: true)
```

in `production.rb` (or the appropriate Heroku environment like `staging.rb` where the error is being thrown in the build pipeline)

[*Source*](https://github.com/lautis/uglifier/issues/127)

Comment: Hey there, I just tried your suggestion but it seems that when pushing to Heroku after the changes that I still get them same error message.

Comment: @JacquesNallétamby just to make sure, you did `git add` and `git commit` after making the changes to the `production.rb` file and before trying to push again?

Comment: @VIktor, Yes, I can confirm that I did but still getting the error of "Uglifier::Error: Unexpected token name «scoreName», expected punc «,»." when trying to push.

Comment: @JacquesNallétamby Did you take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46270497/heroku-push-execjsruntimeerror-syntaxerror-name-expected) ? Looks very similar to your issue

Comment: https://github.com/lautis/uglifier/issues/142 stated that Harmony implementation is halted.

Comment: I also recommend making sure `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` works locally before pushing to heroku.

Comment: This is implied, but to be explicit: All environments in Heroku that precompile need to be updated with the harmony flag.  In my case changing `production.rb` alone was not enough, I also needed to update the `staging.rb` for the staging environment which lives between development and production for the Heroku build to be successful.